# how to split a string and store the first half in a array in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a column in my spreadsheet like below

```
Login 11:30,
Login 11:30,
Logout 11:30,
Login 11:30,
Logout 09:30,
Login 09:30
```

I want to split (Login/Logout and Time) and I want to store the first half (i.e Login/Logout) in an array

```
function cabList(cabID, column1) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Input1');
    var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
    var length = data.length,
        count1 = 0,
        count2 = 0,
        outputArray = [],
        shiftData = [],
        temp = [];
    var shift = ss.getRange(3, 11, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var tt = shift[i].split(" ");
        shiftData[i] = tt[0];
        if (data[i][column1] === cabID && shiftData[i] === 'Login') {
            count1 += 1;
        } else if (data[i][column1] === cabID && shiftData[i] === 'Logout') {
            count2 += 1;
        }
    }
    temp[0] = cabID;
    temp[1] = count1;
    temp[2] = count2;
    outputArray.push(temp);
}
```

I'm trying this code but i'm getting an error called

> TypeError: Cannot find function split in object Login 11:30

Comment: function cabList(cabID,column1)
{
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Input1');
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
var length = data.length,count1=0,count2=0,outputArray = [], shiftData=[],temp = [];
var shift=ss.getRange(3,11, ss.getLastRow(),1).getValues();  
for(i=0;i<length;i++){
var tt=shift[i].split(" ");
shiftData[i]=tt[0]; 
if(data[i][column1]===cabID && shiftData[i]==='Login'){
count1+=1;}
else if (data[i][column1]===cabID && shiftData[i]==='Logout'){
count2+=1;}}
temp[0]=cabID;
temp[1]=count1;
temp[2]=count2;
outputArray.push(temp);}

Comment: i'm trying this code but i'm getting an error called "TypeError: Cannot find function split in object Login 11:30"

Answer (score 0):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var finalarray = {};

for(var i=1; i<=sheet.getRange("a1:a6").getValues().length; i++){
  var testcol = sheet.getRange("a"+i).getValue();
  var tt=testcol.split(" ");
  finalarray[i-1] = tt[0];
}
Logger.log(finalarray);
```

====================================================

```
function cabList(cabID, column1) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Input1');
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
var length = data.length,
count1 = 0,
count2 = 0,
outputArray = [],
shiftData = [],
temp = [];

for(var i = 3; i<=ss.getLastRow(); i++){
  for(var j = 11; j>=1; j--){
    var shift = sheet.getRange(i, j, i, 1).getValue();
    var tt = shift.split(" ");
    shiftData[k] = tt[0];
    k++;
    if (data[i][column1] === cabID && shiftData[i] === 'Login') {
        count1 += 1;
    } else if (data[i][column1] === cabID && shiftData[i] === 'Logout') {
        count2 += 1;
    }
  }
}
temp[0] = cabID;
temp[1] = count1;
temp[2] = count2;
outputArray.push(temp);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: i'm trying the following code but i'm getting an error called "TypeError: Cannot find function split in object Login 11:30"

Comment: what range have you put within getRange() function ? coz it works proper in my file..

Comment: function cabList(cabID,column1){ var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Input1');var data=ss.getDataRange().getValues();var length=data.length, count1=0,count2=0,outputArray=[],shiftData=[],temp = [];
var shift=ss.getRange(3, 11, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
for(i=0;i<length;i++){
var tt=shift[i].split(" ");
shiftData[i]=tt[0];
if(data[i][column1]=== cabID && shiftData[i]=== 'Login'){
count1+=1;}
else if (data[i][column1] === cabID && shiftData[i] === 'Logout'){
count2+=1;}}
temp[0]=cabID;
temp[1]=count1;
temp[2]=count2;
outputArray.push(temp);
}